# Comparing Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create dynamic table views.  I have two arrays.  I want to create a string if there is a match.

Here are the arrays:

## 1

```
(
    [0] => 20
    [optionid] => 20
)
```

## 2

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [1] => GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 1, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Color'
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [22] => GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 22, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Crystal Color'
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [25] => GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 25, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Gauge'
    )

 [3] => Array
    (
        [35] => GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 35, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Height'
    )

 [4] => Array
    (
        [18] => GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 18, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Length'
    )

 [5] => Array
    (
        [33] => GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 33, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Pieces in Pack'
    )

 [6] => Array
    (
        [26] => GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 26, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Pincher Size'
    )

 [7] => Array
    (
        [24] => GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 24, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Rack'
    )

 [8] => Array
    (
        [20] => GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 20, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Ring Size'
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [2] => GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 2, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Size'
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [34] => GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 34, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Size in Pack'
    )
```

)

For example, value 20 on the first array matches key 20 on the second so I want the value added to a string.  If they are more than two matches I want the string to be appended.

the end result should look like

```
$string = "GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 20, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Ring Size'"
```

if more than one match.

```
$string = "GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = 20, value_name, NULL)) AS 'Ring Size', NEXT MATCHED VALUE"
```

Comment: Easily one of the most awkward array structures I've seen in a while. Why are the indexes all over the place?

Comment: the indexes on the second array subarrays is an attribute I'm trying to match to the first array.  The first array is a mysql result.  I built the second one so I can change it if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the array out if you can, so instead of $array[0][20], its simply accessed by $array[20].

Then you can just loop over the option id's you need, pull out the string and append it to a master sql string, along with appending a ', '. 
After the loop you can then just rtrim($string, ", ") to remove the final comma

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at it, I don't think you *need* to do it the way you're doing it (with the full statement in the array). There's only two things that change in the statement, so put the `id` and `alias` into an array and find by that:

```
<?php

function getConcat($id) {
    $group = "GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = %d, value_name, NULL)) AS `%s`";

    $groups = array(
        1  => 'Color',
        2  => 'Size',
        18 => 'Length',
        20 => 'Ring Size',
        22 => 'Crystal Color',
        24 => 'Rack',
        25 => 'Gauge',
        26 => 'Pincher Size',
        33 => 'Pieces in Pack',
        34 => 'Size in Pack',
        35 => 'Height'
    );

    if ((!is_string($id) && !is_numeric($id)) || !isset($groups[$id])) {
        return '';
    }

    return sprintf($group, $id, $groups[$id]);
}

echo getConcat(22)."\n\n";
echo getConcat(50)."\n\n";
echo getConcat(35)."\n\n";
echo getConcat(18)."\n\n";
echo getConcat(1)."\n\n";

?>
```

http://codepad.org/n1eCdv4H

The above will give you the query statement. You could setup a function to also recursively concatenate a list of statements as well:

```
<?php

function getConcatList($arrList=array(), $strList=NULL) {
    $group = "GROUP_CONCAT(if(optionid = %d, value_name, NULL)) AS `%s`";

    if (!is_string($arrList) && !is_numeric($arrList) && !is_array($arrList)) {
        return '';
    } else if (is_string($arrList) || is_numeric($arrList) && !empty($arrList)) {
        $arrList = array($arrList);
    }

    $groups = array(
        1  => 'Color',
        2  => 'Size',
        18 => 'Length',
        20 => 'Ring Size',
        22 => 'Crystal Color',
        24 => 'Rack',
        25 => 'Gauge',
        26 => 'Pincher Size',
        33 => 'Pieces in Pack',
        34 => 'Size in Pack',
        35 => 'Height'
    );

    $c_list = array_shift($arrList);

    if ($groups[$c_list]) {
        $c_strList = sprintf($group, $c_list, $groups[$c_list]);

        if (strlen($strList)) {
            $c_strList = "$strList, $c_strList";
        }
    } else {
        $c_strList = $strList;
    }

    if (!count($arrList)) {
        return $c_strList;
    }

    return getConcatList($arrList, $c_strList);
}

echo getConcatList(22)."\n\n";
echo getConcatList(50)."\n\n";
echo getConcatList(array(35, 33))."\n\n";
echo getConcatList(array(1, 18, 35, 33))."\n\n";
echo getConcatList(array(1, 18, 70, 35, 33))."\n\n";

?>
```

http://codepad.org/jsIFpWkt